# How to add null terminator to char pointer, when using strcpy

Tags: c, pointers, char, malloc, strcpy

I have a program that's attempting to use the `strcpy()` function. I know that when one uses a char array such as: `char array[10]` the null terminator can be set by: `array[0] = '\0';` However, how would I go about setting the null terminator(s) when using char pointers?

**EDIT: The program compiles, but gives garbage as output**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *target;
    char *src = "Test";

    target = malloc(sizeof(char));
    src = malloc(sizeof(char));

     strcpy(target,src);
     printf("%c\n",target); 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to. Second argument of `strcpy()` needs to be `nul` terminated, and the first needs to fit the number of characters in source + the `nul` terminator.

The problems in your code are:

1. You are using `sizeof` operator in wrong way and you are overwriting the `src` pointer by allocating memory again to it.

   To get the length of a string you need `strlen()` and you don't need to call `malloc()` on every pointer.

   You are getting garbage value because you are copying from uninitialized data since `src` points to a newly allocated space, because of

   ```
   src = malloc(sizeof(char));
   ```

   you should not do that.
2. `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition, so you are allocating space for just 1 byte, which if it was to be a valid C string, has to be `'\0'` because there is room for just 1 character.
3. The correct `printf()` specifier for a string is `"%s"`, you are using `"%c"` which is for a character.

The correct way to do it is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char       *target;
    const char *src;

    src    = "Test"; /* point to a static string literal */
    target = malloc(1 + strlen(src)); /* allocate space for the copy of the string */
    if (target == NULL) /* check that nothing special happened to prevent tragedy  */
        return -1;

    strcpy(target, src);
    printf("%s\n", target);
    /* don't forget to free the malloced pointer */
    free(target);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But I get garbage as output.

Comment: Still provides garbage as output on my compiler. Also, on ideone the output is empty: https://ideone.com/duBdgX

Comment: Never mind, you've just edited it again. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @user20842454566 yes, the code at the `ideone` had the wrong `printf()` specifier.

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
strcpy(target,src);
```

`src` is not null-terminated. This invokes undefined behaviour.

Also, by using `malloc(sizeof(char));` you're allocating memory for ony a single `char` element. which is *probably* you don't want.

Next, as per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) of `strcpy()`,  (emphasis mine)

> The `strcpy()` function copies the string pointed to by `src`, **including the terminating null byte (`'\0'`)** to the buffer pointed to by `dest`. The strings may not overlap, and **the destination string `dest` must be large enough to receive the copy**.

so, as long as

1. your source is a proper null-terminated char array (*string*)
2. destination is having enough memory to hold the containts of source

you're good to go. So, you've to

1. null-terminate the `src` array.
2. allocate enough memory to `target` so that it can hold the contains of `src`.

Lastly, to mention, once you've used a string, you're supposed to use the `%s` format specifier with `printf()` to print the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
target = malloc(10);
```

Have memory to accommodate the string and a nul terminator. I don't get why you are allocating memory for `src` as I see you are using a string literal. Just allocate enough memory for destination and do `strcpy()` make sure you are not writing to array out of bound.

The right way would be to

```
target = malloc((strlen(src) + 1));
```

Make a note that when you do

```
char *src = "Test";
```

The string `"Test"` is stored in a read-only location and the address of this location is returned to `src`. So your string is already in memory and no need to allocate memory for this again which you are trying to do and doing it wrongly. So get rid of `malloc()` for `src`

Answer (score 1):

```
man strcpy
```

> DESCRIPTION
>   The  strcpy()  function copies the string pointed to by src, including the terminating null byte ('\0'), to the buffer pointed to by dest.

So you don't have to add null-terminate byte if src has it already.

> BUGS
>   If the destination string of a strcpy() is not large enough, then  anything  might  happen.

So :

```
char *src = "Test"; //  4 chars + '\0'
target = malloc(sizeof(char)); // Space for 1 char
 strcpy(target,src); // Woops !
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers thus far have addressed the flaws in your code and your apparent misunderstanding rather than your question. Pointers to memory can be indexed just like arrays, so given:

```
char *target = malloc( 10 ) ;
```

One can set elements thus:

```
target[0] = '\0' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sourav Ghosh's answer is correct, but for this specific case you should use [strdup()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) as it handles both memory allocation and copying for you:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *src = "Test";   // You should make this const
    char *target = strdup(src); // Duplicate             
    if (target == NULL) {       // Check
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%s\n", target);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```